# Carregar JS externo em app Cordova + Windows 8.1

Tags: javascript, html, apache-cordova, windows-phone-8-1

Atualmente desenvolvi um app html com Angular onde preciso fazer um checkout transparente no PagSeguro. Para tanto eles pedem a inclusão de um JS externo:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stc.pagseguro.uol.com.br/pagseguro/api/v2/checkout/pagseguro.directpayment.js"></script>
```

Na aplicação Web, Cordova + Android e Cordova + Windows 10 não tive problemas (alterando a tag meta de segurança, claro). Mas no app Cordova + Windows 8.1 esse script não carrega! 
Lendo sobre o assunto descobri que isso não é novidade pois o Windows 8 possui uma política de acesso restrito de apps HTML à conteúdo externo como CSS, Imagens e JS por questões de segurança.

Tentei fazer o download desse JS do PagSeguro e inserir manualmente no projeto, porém ocorrem vários erros JS devido a demais solicitações que este arquivo faz.

A pergunta então é: como burlar isso? Como eu poderia obter esse JS sem toda essa dor de cabeça?

Answer (score 0):

Sim, existe uma forma sim! Bem como fizeram uma "gambiarra" pra colocar mapas do Google Maps, dá pra usar a mesma técnica. Basta inserir um iframe:

```
<iframe src="ms-appx-web:///pagseguro.html"></iframe>
```

Esta página "pagseguro.html" é um arquivo local na pasta WWW do Cordova e deve conter o link para o script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stc.pagseguro.uol.com.br/pagseguro/api/v2/checkout/pagseguro.directpayment.js"></script>
```